# Trigger Build (CI) pipeline from Release (CD )pipeline?

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I know it is unconventional to trigger build pipeline from release pipeline, but in my case that is my need. In Azure DevOps I have a build pipeline that triggers release pipeline, then once all of the stages are done in my release, I would like to trigger another build pipeline. That build pipeline will be responsible to update a json file in my git repo. To be able to access the git repo and make changes/commit, I need to use a build pipeline. I have a workaround that clones the git repo in release pipeline and does the update, but that doesn't "feel right". I am hoping to find a better solution.

Note: In git commit message I will have `[skip ci]`, so there won't be an infinite loop of triggers or pipelines...

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to try out any of these 3rd party tasks which lets you call a build pipeline from your release. But I cannot vouch for any.

[image]

If you have trust issues like me :) you could use the DevOps REST.API to trigger your build pipeline.

Basically, you need to make a POST request to trigger a pipeline:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

For that, you could use a PowerShell task added as the last step in your release pipeline.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example-powershell-script-access-rest-api

Also, remember to set up the OAuth token access permissions under "Run on agent" task's "Additional options".

[image]

Also, the build pipeline you are trying to trigger should have given the "Queue builds" permission for your build service.

[image]

Here's an similar script which you should be able to reuse:

```
$alias = "$(Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias)"
$buildIdKey = "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_" + $alias + "_BUILDID"
$buildId = (Get-item env:$buildIdKey).Value
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$authHeader = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"   
$requestHeader = @{
   "Authorization" = $authHeader
   "Accept" = "application/json"
}
$requestBody = '{
    "definition": {
        "id": ' + $buildId + ' 
    }
}'
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $requestHeader -Body $requestBody
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```